# Why do I get an error in bcp query out where clause?

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to SQL Server and write this query for save select result into csv file:

```
declare @Cycle_ID as int
set @Cycle_ID = 0

EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select [Telno],[Cycle],[Price] FROM [ClubEatc].[dbo].[CycleAnalysisTable] where cast([Price] as float)>'+ @Cycle_ID +' " queryout d:\download\behi.csv -t"|" -c -S VM_TAZMINDARAMA -U behzad -P beh1368421'
```

In `where` clause I write simple variable, but I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Please don't decrease my question! I'm new! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't recognize expressions in `exec` statements.  So, try setting up the query first in a variable and using that:

```
declare @Cycle_ID as int;
set @Cycle_ID = 0;
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = '
bcp "select [Telno],[Cycle],[Price] FROM [ClubEatc].[dbo].[CycleAnalysisTable] where cast([Price] as float)>'+ cast(@Cycle_ID as varchar(255)) +' ";

EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @sql queryout d:\download\behi.csv -t"|" -c -S VM_TAZMINDARAMA -U behzad -P beh1368421';
```

It seems curious to me that you are comparing a column called `Price` to a variable called `@Cycle_ID`, but that has nothing to do with the syntax issue.

Comment: Error converting data type varchar to float.

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi . . . Yes, of course.  The variable is defined as a numeric value so it needs to be cast to a string when using `+` for string concatenation.

Comment: thanks,now get Command(s) completed successfully.
but file not create

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi . . . Get the bcp command to work using direct SQL.  Then when it works, figure out how to wrap it in `exec`.

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi  you'll be better off later if you learn with the guidance Gordon has provided versus asking for someone to do your job or course work.